# What is the authenticity of the hadith that if Moses and Jesus were alive they would have to follow the prophet?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

Can someone check the authenticity and translation for this narration:
[image]

> “If Moses and Jesus were alive, they would have had no choice but to
> follow me.”
> (Tafsir Ibni Kathir, Under the Verse ‘Mithaqun-Nabiyyin’; Al-Yawaqitu
> wal-Jawahir, Volume 2, Under Al-Mabhathuth-Thani wath-Thalathun,
> Zarqani Sharah Mawahibul-Luduniyyah; Fathul-Bayan, Al-Bahrul-Muhit,)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a variation on the well known hadith where Umar ibn al-Khattab brought a page from the Torah or something from the writings of the Jews, and the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ disapproved of it, telling us to not take anything from the ahl al-kitab, as we could mistakenly deny something which is true or affirm something which is false. And finally he said that even if Moses عليه السلام was alive today he would have no choice but to follow Muhammad ﷺ. This is present in e.g. [Musnad Ahmad](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13157/14934). It has some weakness but is corroborated.

The hadith does not mention Jesus عليه السلام, and there is no recorded chain for the version which mentions him. It is likely a delusion.

> وهو حديث محفوظ ، دون ذكر عيسى فيه ، فإنه منكر عندي لم أره في شيء من طرقه
>
> al-Albani; footnote on [شرح الطحاوية ابن أبي العز](https://shamela.ws/book/10549/510#p1)

Comment: Wouldn't Jesus follow the teachings of Prophet Muhammad on his second coming?

Comment: @Ahmed This post is about whether Jesus is mentioned in the wording of this specific hadith. It is obvious that Jesus would follow the teachings of Prophet Muhammad ﷺ on his second coming, but that is tangential to what we are talking about here.